# probability measure on space of sequences

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega=\{0,1\}^\infty$. For some $n$, let $B\subset \{0,1\}^n$.

I have seen these two statements which make me confused little bit.

(1) If $A\subset \Omega$, $A=B\times \{0,1\}^\infty$, and then it says that the probability of $A$ is defined as $$P(A)=|B|/2^{n}.$$

Somewhere else it says, the probability of $\sigma\in\{0,1\}^k$ is given by

$$P[\omega:(\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_k)=\sigma]=1/2^k.$$

What is the connection between these two statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first follows from the second. The second tells you the probability of the set of sequences that begin like $\sigma$. If you want to get the probability of $B\times\{0,1\}^\infty$ you can use additivity and the second statement to deduce that it is $|B|/2^k$: $P(B\times\{0,1\}^\infty)=\sum_{\sigma\in B}P(\{\sigma\}\times\{0,1\}^\infty)$$=\sum_{\sigma\in B}1/2^k$.

Comment: In this notes http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/280_06-07/Lecture_Notes/N9.pdf, Example 2.6-2.7. As I get it the second followed from the first. Could please explain more. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that too. They are equivalent. The second follows from the first by taking $B$ of cardinality one: $B=\{\sigma\}$.

Comment: Other comments are also welcome. Thanks for Nathanson.